# Mandalorian quote along the lines of "We have no word for hero"

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-wars-legends

I recall, from Legends, a quote along the lines of;

> There is no Mando word for hero. To stand up for yourself, your
>   family, your clan, that's expected. It's only cowards we needed to
>   find a word for.

This directly relates to Mando'a culture. Can anyone remind me of the origins of this quote?

Comment: @Molag Bal; sorry, what edit did you make? Was it just for the badge? As far as I can see, the question was exactly as I phrased it.

Comment: I added the franchise tag [star-wars]. To my knowledge, there are no badges available for retagging beyond the first time.

Comment: But it's not Star Wars, it's specifically Legends. Otherwise I am sure a Google search would answer my question.

Comment: We use [star-wars] for all questions about Star Wars, be it Legends or not.

Comment: It's probably from the Republic Commando series of books.

Comment: @Null; I don't think it is. It's very much on those lines, but if it originates in there, then it was as a quote. I have those books and they've all be reread multiple times.

Comment: It was from a book, though?

Comment: That quote shows up in the [Wookieepedia article for Mando'a](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mando%27a/Legends), and is attributed to [Baltan Carid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Baltan_Carid) from the Legacy of the Force series. It's a Karen Traviss quote, which is why I suspected the Republic Commando books.

Comment: It wasn't. Gods all be damned, I looked at that. I really did and I even used "Find on page" for the word "hero". I really did search hard for this quote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote is from the book *[Legacy of the Force: Revelation (2008)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Revelation)* and is spoken by [Baltan Carid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Baltan_Carid), a Mandalorian warrior.

In full, it says:

> "We don't have a word for hero. Being prepared to die for your family
>   and friends, or what you hold dear, is a basic requirement for a
>   Mando, so it's not worth a separate word. It's only cowards we had to
>   find a special name for."

Comment: Baltan Carid. Thank you.